# Header view css class depending on content

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have my website layout structured this way:

header

--content

footer

Where header and footer are @included.

On some pages I have this classes to body
`<body class="property-map-append-top has-breadcrumb">` and to other pages: `<body class="property-map-append-top">`

How can I do this for specified pages?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by 'some pages'. You could pass a variable from a controller, like `hasBreadrumb` and use it in Blade template:

```
<body class="property-map-append-top @if($hasBreadcrumb)has-breadcrumb@endif">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I do this in my views:

```
<body class="{{ $bodyClass or 'default-body-class' }}">
```

You can add classes to the `$bodyClass` variable in your controllers, but only when you want to override the default class (the string which comes after the 'or'). With this syntax you can opt to not send the variable to the view and still avoid an error.